# The target origin provided does not match the recipient window's origin (Rocket chat)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, cross-domain

My [Rocket chat](https://rocket.chat/) is hosted at https://chat.mydomain.com

My web app (where the iframe is) is hosted at https://app.mydomain.com

I've been able to register the user fine on the back, returning an authToken when they login. When I try the to post the authLogin back to the iframe from within my ReactJS application...

```
<iframe src="https://chat.mydomain.com/?layout=embedded" onLoad={() => this.login()} />

...

onLoad(){
    window.parent.postMessage({
        event: 'login-with-token',
        loginToken: authToken
    }, 'https://chat.mydomain.com');
}
```

... I get the following error however:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://chat.mydomain.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://app.mydomain.com').
```

Any ideas?

p.s. Ive enabled iframe integration in the settings as well as enabled CORS.

Answer (score 3):

Try to the following:

```
onLoad(){
    window.parent.postMessage({
        event: 'login-with-token',
        loginToken: authToken
    }, '*');
}
```

Or putting a id iframe:

```
<iframe id = "myiframe" src="https://chat.mydomain.com/?layout=embedded" onLoad={() => this.login()} />
```

...

```
onLoad(){
     document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.parent.postMessage({
        event: 'login-with-token',
        loginToken: authToken
    }, '*');
}
```